Custom Glassblock Window came in 2 pieces
I just picked up a 52”x28” glass block window that I custom ordered. However, it came in 2 pieces (over 40” comes in 2 pieces apparently). I know how to install into the basement wall but I have some questions about joining it together. It looks like some sort of adhesive (not mortar) is between all the blocks then the outside edges are clearish silicone. What is recommended for this? Do I need spacers? And should I band the whole assembly together?

Surely there was instructional literature provided with the kit, no?

I think your best answer will come from the company/people you got the block window from. If it's a matter of routine to "split" anything over a specific width, they surely must provide some direction about how to join the pieces back together. I would imagine that "clearish silicone" and appropriate spacers are probably somewhere on the right track.

Nope no paper work with it.

Got a product link? We're throwing darts in the dark without more information.

Are the two blocks glued together when they came, or they supplied an adhesive for you to apply?

https://www.menards.com/main/measuremententry.html?cid=13271
I’ve sent Menards an email but haven’t heard anything back yet. It’s like a basement glass block window that you’d buy preassembled and just mortar into the opening. But instead of it coming in one piece, it is two.

The following was boosted directly from Menard's website:

Speedset Glass Block Clear Silicone Sealant/Adhesive - 10.1 oz
Model Number: 2002 Menards ® SKU: 4057227

By using clear silicone to grout between the blocks you will simulate
a beautifully modern all-glass look. This silicone-based system is an
easy assembly alternative to the classic mortar-based process in
building your windows and panels. A single tube of silicone is
sufficient to bond and grout approximately 10 to 12 blocks.
Features:

Specially formulated to secure vinyl track in mortar-free glass block systems
Bonds 3" or 4" glass blocks together
Provides permanent flexibility and ensures long-term performance
Adheres well to glass, vinyl, wood, and metals
Good cold weather adhesion
Mold and mildew resistant
Low VOC means low odor
Can be used both indoors and outdoors
10.1 ounce tube works with all brands of glass block


